# I'm receiving an error in my bots code.. idk what to do

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py

So basically, I took my time to make a discord.py bot (I think the the version is 1.5.0 or 1.5.6)
and I went to Heroku where everything was working fine.
But then got this error

```
" File "/app/lib/db/db.py", line 42
if (fetch := cur.fetchone()) is not None:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"
```

But everything was working OK locally.
what did I do wrong?
I checked the error and went back on the tutorial I was following and what I wrote is good, there's no typo.

Comment: On your local machine, I'm guessing you have Python 3.8, which supports the "walrus operator" or assignment expression operator (`:=`), whereas your heroku environment has an older version of Python, which does not support this operator.

Comment: So how do I fix this? @PaulM.

Answer (score 1):

This is new grammar in python3.8,

Edit your `runtime.txt` to config using python 3.8.

```
python-3.8.6
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes